# ООП для дерева - верно ли применение?

Tags: python, алгоритм, ооп, дерево

Изучаю сплей-деревья, решил использовать статью с положительными отзывами с разбором и с кодом с habr: https://habr.com/ru/company/JetBrains-education/blog/210296/

В статье вершины описываются классом, при этом нет комментария, как код работает с многими вершинами. Возможно, моих практических знаний не хватает для понимания процесса создания элементов класса (ООП я изучил, но на практике не использовал, функционального подхода хватало).

Поэтому для работы кода я ввел список `li`, куда помещаю экземпляры класса один за другим (один экземпляр - одна вершина), все перестроение дерева - только сменой указателей на детей и родителей, сам список не сортирую. Разумеется, пришлось весь код переписать под список (часть моего кода - ниже).

**Вопрос: верно ли я сделал, или код можно было не менять, а с вершинами как-то по-другому поступить надо - более по ООП или более эффективно?**

*Пример кода из статьи (с цитатами), весь код из статьи приведен ниже согласно запросу в комментарии:*

"Для описания структуры дерева нам пригодится простенький класс, описывающий отдельную вершину,"

```
class Node:
  def __init__(self, key, left = None, right = None, parent = None):
    self.left   = left
    self.right  = right
    self.parent = parent
    self.key    = key
```

"и две вспомогательные процедуры для работы с указателями на родителей."

```
def set_parent(child, parent):
  if child != None:
    child.parent = parent

def keep_parent(v):
  set_parent(v.left, v)
  set_parent(v.right, v)
```

и процедура вставки:

```
def insert(root, key):
  left, right = split(root, key)
  root = Node(key, left, right)
  keep_parent(root)
  return root
```

*Мой соответствующий кусок кода со списком* (класс не повторяю, он описан так же, как в статье, вызовы функций не привожу для уменьшения объема вопроса):

```
def set_parent(child, parent):
    if child != None:
        # Изменение относительно исходного кода
        li[child].parent = parent  

def keep_parent(v):
    # Изменения относительно исходного кода 
    set_parent(li[v].left, v)  
    set_parent(li[v].right, v) 

def insert(root, key):
    left, right = split(root, key)
    # Изменение относительно исходного кода 
    li[root] = Node(key, left, right)
    keep_parent(root)
    return root

# Объявление списка
li = []
n = input()
for _ in range (n): 
    number = input () 
    # Добавление в список вершины
    li.append(Node(number))
```

Полный код из статьи https://habr.com/ru/company/JetBrains-education/blog/210296/:

```
class Node:
  def __init__(self, key, left = None, right = None, parent = None):
    self.left   = left
    self.right  = right
    self.parent = parent
    self.key    = key

def set_parent(child, parent):
  if child != None:
    child.parent = parent

def keep_parent(v):
  set_parent(v.left, v)
  set_parent(v.right, v)

def rotate(parent, child):
  gparent = parent.parent
  if gparent != None:
    if gparent.left == parent:
      gparent.left = child
    else:
      gparent.right = child

  if parent.left == child:
    parent.left, child.right = child.right, parent
  else:
    parent.right, child.left = child.left, parent

  keep_parent(child)
  keep_parent(parent)
  child.parent = gparent

def splay(v):
  if v.parent == None:
    return v
  parent = v.parent
  gparent = parent.parent
  if gparent == None:
    rotate(parent, v) 
    return v    
  else:
    zigzig = (gparent.left == parent) == (parent.left == v)
    if zigzig:
      rotate(gparent, parent)
      rotate(parent, v)
    else:
      rotate(parent, v)
      rotate(gparent, v)
    return splay(v)

def find(v, key):
  if v == None:
    return None
  if key == v.key:
    return splay(v)
  if key < v.key and v.left != None:
    return find(v.left, key)
  if key > v.key and v.right != None:
    return find(v.right, key)
  return splay(v)

def split(root, key):
  if root == None:
    return None, None
  root = find(root, key)
  if root.key == key:
    set_parent(root.left, None)
    set_parent(root.right, None)
    return root.left, root.right
  if root.key < key:
    right, root.right = root.right, None
    set_parent(right, None)
    return root, right
  else:
    left, root.left = root.left, None
    set_parent(left, None)
    return left, root 

def insert(root, key):
  left, right = split(root, key)
  root = Node(key, left, right)
  keep_parent(root)
  return root

def merge(left, right):
  if right == None:
    return left
  if left == None:
    return right
  right = find(right, left.key)
  right.left, left.parent = left, right
  return right

def remove(root, key):
  root = find(root, key)
  set_parent(root.left, None)
  set_parent(root.right, None)
  return merge(root.left, root.right)
```

Comment: где объявлен `li`? Кто им владеет?

Comment: `li` объявлен мной в `main` (самый низ кода) и указан в примере кода с комментарием                                 `# Объявление списка`. Именно про него я и писал "Поэтому для работы кода я ввел список" (при этом я не уверен, что это лучшее решение для хранения дерева, как я и пишу в вопросе).

Comment: Сам по себе вопрос слабо сформулирован, без кода из статьи не очень ясно в чем его суть. Да и ответ на "правильно ли я сделал" невозможно дать объективно. У меня есть предположения в чем вопрос, попробую тут выяснить наводящими вопросами. Самый главный, почему вы пишете, что "процесса создания элементов класса нет"? Функция `insert` это и делает - добавляет в дерево элементы создавая экземпляры класса

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для обширной дискуссии предлагаю [продолжить обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/137518/)

Comment: Код из статьи полностью добавлен.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Благодаря комментариям Романа (цитаты ниже) стало ясно, что я неверно понимал, как код организует хранение элементов дерева.

Ответ на вопрос: сделал я неверно, код **нужно** было не менять для хранения элементов дерева.

Если коротко, то все элементы, создаваемые кодом статьи, - это объекты без имени, которые код сам ищет по своим указателям, размещённым в этих объектах. Отчасти для этого класс и используется.

"`insert` создает новый корневой и в него добавляет куски существующего дерева. Для работы с деревом (а там всего две операции: `insert` - добавление нового элемента и `find` - поиск элемента) нужно иметь ссылку на корневой узел, именно она подается на вход, что в `insert`, что в `find`. Остальные узлы доступны из корневого по цепочке `left` и `right`. `find`, например, при поиске решает куда двигаться по дереву (т.е. в какое поддерево от текущего узла) вправо или влево.

Работа с деревом выглядит так:

Сначала дерево пустое: `tree = None`

Добавляем первый элемент:
`tree = insert(tree, 3)`,

и так далее:
`tree = insert(tree, value_to_insert)`

Т.е. в `tree` клиент, использующий дерево, хранит ссылку на корень дерева, другие вершины он не должнен хранить. Операции модификации всегда возвращают новый корень дерева, который клиент должен сохранить и использовать в дальшейнем"